# Js: get the domain name minus all params and irrelevant data

Tags: javascript, regex, url

Is there a way to get **only** the domain name from a given string.

Lets say the string is:

```
var url = "https://subdimain.thedomain.com/this/path/file.html"
```

All I want to get is:

> thedomain.com

however, there are many factors I am not sure how to account for. For example:

- https or http
- subdomain or none
- tld (.com/.co.uk/.in/.fr) etc....
- path etc.. (/this/path/file.html)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Turnip Thanks, this helped :)

Answer (score -2):

Here's an easy way:

```js
function domain(url){
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  var s = a.hostname.split('.'), d = s.length-2;
  return s[d]+'.'+s[d+1];
}
var sub = domain('https://subdimain.thedomain.com/this/path/file.html');
console.log(sub);
```

Comment: That would also include the subdomain.